# After login, desktop hangs for ~20s before showing Unity. Bootchart suggests pactl. Help?

Tags: 14.04, boot, unity, sound, pulseaudio

After I log in to my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop, I see my desktop background for approximately 20 seconds before the actual Unity desktop loads. I installed [bootchart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) and that suggests that the problem is that `pactl` is being called and taking a long time to do something, and that the main desktop startup is blocked on that:

[image]

How can I identify where this `pactl` call is, and why it might be taking a long time?

Logs from pulseaudio startup are at: http://kryogenix.org/random/pulseverbose/.

Comment: try to comment out the string "Exec=start-pulseaudio-x11" in /etc/xgd/autostart/pulseaudio.desktop and do the same for  /etc/xgd/autostart/pulseaudio-kde.desktop and see how it goes!

Comment: if the above doesn't work try removing both pulseaudio-kde.desktop and pulseaudio.desktop (back them up somewhere) your audio will still work not to worry about that.

Comment: erm... won't that disable pulseaudio?

Comment: you need to identify first the cause before worrying about your pulseaudio and no it wont disable as I said above, it will just disable the autostart that is all....

Comment: Agree with @ostendali and @Dee; try disabling the offending startup process.  *If* that makes startup fast, then try reenabling it with logging as Dee suggests, and see what shows up.

Comment: I don't know what the offending startup process is. As you see from bootchart, it's pactl, but I don't know where it's called from.

Comment: I just told you in my first comment!

Answer (score 8):

For **Diagnosis** (not the solution) you should enable logging on `pactl` module:

- edit (with sudo) following file

  ```
  /etc/pulse/client.conf
  ```
- and add following line to the file

  ```
  extra-arguments = -vvvv --log-target=newfile:/tmp/pulseverbose.log --log-time=1
  ```
- After reboot log in `/tmp/pulseverbose.log` will hopefully contain potential problem of pulse audio control. There could be more than one file.
- Come back and **paste it here** and we can give you additional hints.
- **Remove!** the line from `/etc/pulse/client.conf` after you finish.

For **Solution** I would first try to reinstall `pulseaudio`, but after we will see logs, possibly this will change. Therefore give us your logs first. Eventually steps to reinstall pulseaudio and alsa could be:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

but this can be helpless for example if your drivers are wrong/crippled by wrong settings etc.

Update: **Diagnosis** from log files:
Core of your problem lies here

```
D (   0.005|   0.000)  [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Loading module-alsa-card with arguments 'device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_03.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"'
D (   3.010|   3.004)  [pulseaudio] reserve-wrap.c: Unable to contact D-Bus session bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-zgX6izEp13: Connection refused
```

followed by many errors like this:

```
I (   3.011|   0.000)  [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:0: No such file or directory
```

which takes your time on startup.

**Proposed solutions:**

1. xxx Looks like there is a temporary socket left open and pulseaudio does not make it over. Please check if there is a `/tmp/dbus-zgX6izEp13` file and if yes, remove it by `sudo rm /tmp/dbus-zgX6izEp13` and try to reboot if there is a change.

   -- **Update**: there is not such a file, means that it is created just before the pulseaudio wants to use it or something wants to write it simultaneously. Some configuration could be michmached/doubled.
2. You can try to purge and reinstall pulseaudio. See the text above.

Please give a short reply if something helps.

Comment: OK, thank you for that. What's the best way to provide the logs? I added to client.conf, rebooted, logged in, and removed from client.conf, and I now have three files: pulseverbose.log, .log.1, and .log.2, of sizes 279K, 2.5K, 313K. I can't paste all of that :-) Are there specific things to look for?

Comment: You can share a link to a file for example on google drive (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WgI8GMo47XU-RWgkDf4_m7P5hiTkiTCc4t06V9WIK2E/edit), or any other fileshare service.

Comment: or try to use http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: OK, log files at http://kryogenix.org/random/pulseverbose/

Comment: @sil could you please add the link to your question? It makes it easier for to find all the relevant information.

Comment: Link added.
Dee, there is no /tmp/dbus-* file at all. I will try reinstalling PA when I have a chance.