# Lockup on logout or shutdown

Tags: shutdown, logout, lockup

just installed Ubuntu, looks good and can share things from MS windows partitions OK.

However, get stuck when I try to logout (2 users setup) or shutdown.
Can still get in remotely from another machine using ssh and shutdown nicely using 'sudo shutdown now' but until the reboot is done the machine / main console is inaccessible.

When using logout the login screen flashes up and then goes away like in the following screenshots. Keyboard is non responsive, however, the AlrtGr SysRq REISUB magic worked once. but to much effort to remember that!

Whoops - new member, no reputation so cannot post images!!
You'll find them here...

login screen - http://brainforge.co.uk/images/test/P1050647.JPG

stuck screen - http://brainforge.co.uk/images/test/P1050646.JPG

---

Just spotted these:
[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS hangs (all black) before showing login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439875/ubuntu-12-04-lts-hangs-all-black-before-showing-login-screen?rq=1)
[After login, desktop hangs for ~20s before showing Unity. Bootchart suggests pactl. Help?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709374/after-login-desktop-hangs-for-20s-before-showing-unity-bootchart-suggests-pac)

I have similar black screen for a few seconds during boot after grub - worrying what's happening?
Also last night did a proper shutdown now and then powered up this morning. Just turned power on and left machine untouched for must be nearly an hour - when I came back it had got into the logo on the stuck screen state!
Could these issues be related?

Comment: Huh? I've never seen the logo on the stuck screen one.